# how to define a new command with at least one mandatory argument, optional arguments and conditional text?

Tags: xparse

I want to construct a command that takes at least one (mandatory) argument and up to many (small many, say 10 or 50) optional arguments. If any optional argument is present, I want the command to include different code.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \myDummy { m o }{
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
        { \DoSomethingJustWithMandatoryArgument {
                publication \hyperref[#1]{ \#\,\ref{#1}}
            } 
        }
        { \DoSomethingWithBothArguments {
                publications \hyperref[#1]{ \#\,\ref{#1}}, \hyperref[#2]{\#\,\ref{#2}}   
            }
        }
}
```

This works well with `\mydummy{a}` and `\mydummy{a}{b}`, producing the desired result.

- How to make it work with many more arguments, say with 3 or 10?
- In terms of syntax, how is it possible to call `\mydummy` with a number of arguments within  `{}`, eg `\mydummy{a}` or `\mydummy{a,b,c,d,e,f}`?

Comment: Wouldn't a syntax such as `\mydummy{a,b,c,d}` be more manageable? You could have any separator instead of the comma.

Comment: `m` stays argument `#2` regardless if `#1` is used or not

Comment: thanks @cgnieder. I updated the question, after learning a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses an `xparse` argument processor (See Sect 3.2 of documentation) to achieve the kind of behavior that's described. I put `\textbf` in place of `\ref` and omitted `\hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{NumberOfArgs}
\setcounter{NumberOfArgs}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand \myDummy { >{\SplitList{,}} m} {%
    \setcounter{NumberOfArgs}{0}%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\Count}% 
    \ifnum\value{NumberOfArgs}>1  Publications \else Publication \fi 
    \setcounter{NumberOfArgs}{1}\ProcessList{#1}{\reference}%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand \Count {m} {\addtocounter{NumberOfArgs}{1}}

\NewDocumentCommand \reference {m} {%
    \ifnum\value{NumberOfArgs}>1 ,\space\else\relax\fi
    \#\,\textbf{#1}%
    \addtocounter{NumberOfArgs}{1}%
    }

\begin{document}

\myDummy{a,b,c}

\myDummy{a}

\myDummy{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

\end{document}
```

[image]